# JsonUnsupportedObjectError i can't solve the error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I am trying to perform insert operation with api. While performing this operation, I want to take the current date and save it with the api. But I am getting error. How can I solve it as soon as possible
here are my codes

```
  var myinsert={"ID":sayac,"MAS_ID":1,"PALET_NO":e.PALETNO,"TARIH":DateTime.now(),"HUCRE_KODU":e.HUCREKODU,"MIKTAR":e.MIKTAR,"HAREKET_TIPI":"PALET TOPLAMA"};
    String uri = 'http://192.168.0.21/api/values/DegerEkle/';
    Uri ur = Uri.parse(uri);

    final response = await http.post(ur, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: jsonEncode(myinsert))
    .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));
    print(response);
```

Here is my error message

```
Exception has occurred.
JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `jsonEncode` to encode instance/ object directly. Refer [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html).

You have to confirm what is the request type that "TARIH" was accepted.

IF it is **String** type:

- Convert `DateTime.now()` to String by adding `.toString()` OR with [`DateFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) to match with the accepted format.

IF it is **int** type (sinceEpoch way):

- `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch()`  OR `DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch()`